# Network Manager disappeared

Tags: gnome-panel, network-manager

3 vertical dots appears instead of Network Manager applet in Panel. I can connect to ethernet but I'm not able to connect to my wireless network. I tried to add/remove the Notification area from the Panel, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible solutions for this problem,

I prefer to take a look at:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/possible-solutions-to-fix-the-missing-network-manager-icon-in-ubuntu-9-10.html`

Regards,
Ilias